# Show that this distribution converges to $0$ in probability.

Tags: probability-theory

Let $p_n\in(0, 1)$ and $X_n :\Omega\rightarrow\Bbb R$ for $n\in N$ be independent random variables with
$$\Bbb P(X_n = 1) = p_n,\quad\Bbb P(X_n = 0) = 1 − p_n.$$
Find an equivalent condition in terms of the sequence $(p_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$: $(X_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ converges to $0$ in probability.

---

So I know by definition that a sequence $(X_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ of random variables $X_n:\Omega\rightarrow\Bbb R$ converges in probability to a random variable $X:\Omega\rightarrow\Bbb R$ if $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\Bbb P(\vert X_n-X\vert\geq\epsilon)=0,$$ for all $\epsilon>0$.

So applying this definition to the question in hand, we have $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\Bbb P(\vert X_n\vert\geq\epsilon).$$ So for $\epsilon=0$, we have $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\Bbb P(\vert X_n\vert\geq 0)=\lim_{n\to\infty}(\Bbb P(X_n=0)+\Bbb P(X_n=1))=\lim_{n\to\infty}1,$$ but that's where I get confused. I'm sure this isn't a correct attempt so where am I going wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Intuitively something like $p_n \to 0$ could work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is clear that for every $1\ge \epsilon>0$ you have
$$
P\{|X_n|\ge\epsilon\}=P\{X_n=1\}=p_n,
$$
so all you need is $\lim p_n=0$.

Comment: Ah I see where I went wrong now, thank you very much for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot take $\varepsilon=0$ because $P(\lvert X_n\rvert\geqslant 0)=1$.

Nevertheless, the choice $\varepsilon=1/2$ leads to $P(\lvert X_n\rvert\geqslant 1/2)\to 0$ which imposes $p_n\to 0$. Now, it remains to see whether this necessary condition is also sufficient.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification!